# Snowflake schema creation from a share

Tags: database, schema, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, share

Wanted to confirm if it is not possible to create a schema from a share.

I see from the documentation that once a share (from a schema not the entire database) is created/enabled by the provider account,I/the consumer account can only leverage the share by creating a new database.

I/Consumer already have a snowflake database & would like to just point the schema from the provider that is enabled as share to a new schema on my side in the existing database. This avoids the need to maintain multiple databases.

Br,
Noor.

Comment: given databases are really a "namespace" in so much a schema is just a name space. Pull the share into it own DB, and then make a view/s from the existing if you want to somehow have everything "under one database"

Comment: Hello Simeon, thank you for the reply. I really wanted to map the schema coming from share directly to a fresh schema in an already existing database on consumer side. I understood the approach you quote. So, technically, there isn't yet a way in Snowflake to achieve my requirement, is it?

Comment: I strongly believe you cannot do want you are asking. But the justification you have given is only a distinction in your head, or in some external tooling that thinks of different databases as a more really different than different tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible.

In consumer side, the ff. command is used to consume a share:

```
CREATE DATABASE <name> FROM SHARE <provider_account>.<share_name>;
```

Hence, consumption can only be done in database level. This effectively creates a read-only database (unlike regular/local databases), all of its objects are controlled by the provider.

Additionally, IMPORTED PRIVILEGES is used to grant roles in consumer side access on **shared database**. Cannot grant this privilege on a Schema.